# Is aliasing namespace within namespace declaration, not namespace import possible in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I'm writing classes in PHP in deep namespace, but I want it to be easier to access. Is there a way to alias namespace within it's definition, not import? It's okay if it's work-around.

I want to achieve it, becouse its very, very commonly used class in code I have on hands, but moving it into more shallow namespace entirely is not an option.

I've tried to google it but all I found was import namespace aliasing, I havent found anything revelant also anything in docs.

Definition file:

```php
namespace \Something\Really\Annoyingly\Deep AS \MyClass

class MyClass{}
```

Other file:

```php
namespace \Something\Else;

use MyClass;

$obj = new MyClass();
```

I used "AS" here for sake of example. I know it will not work, and my question is, is it possible to make it work somehow?

Comment: You do not need to import within the current namespace. I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Namespaces are like packages which a list of classes, interfaces etc under a particular jurisdiction. If you could alias it, then don't provide a namespace in the first place. Another reason is you could very easily alias 2 namespaces with the same name. So now PHP doesn't know which one you are referring to.

Comment: So, if you *could* alias at definition time… the class would be accessible as `\MyClass`… Well, you can do this by omitting the `namespace` entirely. What's the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

The aliases can only be declared at import time, and are file-based.

If you think about it, you'll realize it doesn't make sense it were possible. There is nothing to be gained and a lot to be able to be broken if this was possible.

Comment: Well, I hoped community can prove me wrong and tell me there is a way.